Running Signal App Android App (from Github) on my Computer
I want to build the app on my local computer and especially execute the tests. But I have a lot of troubles with all the different versions of the different packages and libraries. Does anybody have any ideas on how I can resolve it and get all the specific dependencies I need? Is there any program, which can create a pom.xml and or a matching build.gradle out of the project?
tried to add everything manually, but some packages/libraries were not found and some were deprecated

Please provide the link to the project you are trying to build. What have you tried so far and what are the problems you are facing?

https://github.com/signalapp/Signal-Android
adding every dependency manually

That is a gradle project therefore you don't need to add anything manually. Simply execute ./gradlew tasks for details.

./gradlew tasks

Task :build-logic:tools:compileKotlin FAILED
Kotlin does not yet support 22 JDK target, falling back to Kotlin JVM_21 JVM target
Configure project :contacts
Kotlin does not yet support 22 JDK target, falling back to Kotlin JVM_21 JVM target
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.


1: Task failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':build-logic:tools:compileKotlin'.


Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileJava' (17) and 'compileKotlin' (21) Consider using JVM Toolchain: https://kotl.in/gradle/jvm/toolchain


I get this error, do you know what I have to do? I am not familiar with android apps, as you might already have noticed

Please don't post large errors in comment. Edit your question instead. In your case the reason is obvious as it is written in the error message. Your used JDK is too new. For Android development it is better to use JDK 17. In general for development LTS versions of JDK are best. The non-LTS versions are more like beta versions and can be skipped.
